# forward slash escape deleting files

Tags: shell, sed, terminal

I'm running a shell script to remove all metacharacters with sed with this code.

```
for file in /path/to/folder/*; do
   mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed "s,[()\^\$\?*+=\|#!@%&-],,g")"
done
```

It works great, but when I want it to also look for forward slashes ("/") it deletes all files. this is what i used. `s,[/()\^\$\?*+=\|#!@%&-],,g`

Why is that? and how would I also target forward slashes.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `echo $file` will do if your file name contains white space, globbing characters, etc? What do you mean by "metacharacters"? A file name CANNOT contain a "/" character. Also, I see "=" in the list among others that are not RE metacharacters nor are they globbing metacharacters so what is it you're REALLY trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it didn't delete any file but they may have become *hidden* for you since they all start with dot `.` now. Run `ls -al` to see those files.

What has happened is that by including forward slash `/` in your sed command your files are being renamed to something like: `.filename` since very first `/` has been stripped off by sed.

Comment: I don't see them as hidden. I ran ls -al and just saw the typical . .. .DS_Store.

Comment: Any other way around it? I just have co-workers that tend to use metacharacters in their filenames... i know.. i know..

Comment: Why are you including `/` in your sed command since that is also used in file's path.

Comment: because occasionally i'll see filenames that contain `/`. Just want to strip them out.

Comment: No, filenames in Unix/Linux cannot contain a forward slash.

Comment: Well, your command would have resulted in something like `mv /path/to/folder/foo.txt pathtofolderfoo.txt`, or given a relative path `mv ./path/to/folder/foo.txt .pathtofolderfoo.txt`, so, unless you got a bunch of error messages from `mv`, you'll need to check those sorts of file names now...

Comment: Thats essentially the problem. My co-workers sometimes will save files with a `/` on them.. don't know why they do it.. they just do. So i want to find out a way strip them out.. and by the looks of it there isn't? I would just have to individually go and rename them?

Comment: As I commented earlier: **filenames in Unix/Linux cannot contain a forward slash** Try creating a file on your system with a forward slash and you will get error.

Comment: @anubhava thats not the case. I'm precisely testing that and I can save a file with a `/` in them. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I have tried: `touch 'foo/bar'` or `touch 'foo\/bar'` on Linux and OSX and it didn't work any where. Can you please tell me one Unix command/util that succeeds creating a file with / in its name.

Comment: @anubhava these are simply saved files. Say for instance textedit or a photoshop or excel. we're not creating files through command line.

Comment: I'm still puzzled to know how a software succeeded in creating a file with `/`. I tried saving to `foo/bar.rtf` from textedit on my Mac and it created filename `foo:bar.rtf`

Comment: Pls read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename and then http://superuser.com/questions/512584/can-i-rename-a-file-that-contains-a-forward-slash-in-unix

Comment: @anubhava don't know how else to explain it either. I'm baffled by my coworkers.. but it happens and I have to fix it. http://pbrd.co/1767GCn

Comment: Is the `/` in those file names possibly not an ASCII 47 (0x2f), and is instead something Unicode-ish or some other encoding? Unix/Linux may not catch that if it's created through Samba/CIFS or something, I suppose, but I'd have to test that to be sure... Also, your `sed` bits likely wouldn't have caught it either...

Comment: Please check my linked Q&A. Also can you show me output of `ls -al` from a directory that contains filenames with `/` in it.

Comment: @twalberg you're right. it's really a `:` and added that to the regex and it took it out.

Comment: Yes that is expected. This is what I wrote earlier: `I tried saving to foo/bar.rtf from textedit on my Mac and it created filename foo:bar.rtf`

Answer (score 1):

Better use this (don't try to re-invent a square wheel)  :

```
detox /path/to/dir/*
```

See http://detox.sourceforge.net/

> Description    : An utility designed to clean up filenames by replacing characters with standard equivalents