# Create a symbolic link with the name 'dir/file' pointing toward 'target_file'?

Tags: linux, symlink

I'm thinking no... but:

If you have file **~/foo/foo.jpg** and move and rename it to **~/bar.jpg**, is there any way to make a symbolic link (with the original name and structure) inside **~/** and point toward **~/bar.jpg**?

```
~/foo$ ls
foo.jpg
~/foo$ mv foo.jpg ~/bar.jpg
~/foo$ cd ~
    ~$ ls
bar.jpg
    ~$ ln -s bar.jpg 'foo/foo.jpg'
    ~$ ls -l
bar.jpg
foo/foo.jpg -> bar.jpg
```

If there is no way as described above, I can just create a hardlink **~/bar.jpg** point toward **~/foo/foo.jpg**. But I'd rather not have the directory **foo** or file **foo.jpg** at all; just a symbolic link in their place.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic here, but you _may_ get more answers at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for future questions like this.

Comment: You can just `ln -s ~/bar.jpg ~/foo/foo.jpg`.  Or am I missing something in your question?  You could also `ln -s ../bar.jpg ~/foo/foo.jpg`.

Comment: @CodyPiersall I will do that next time, thank you for the advice. If a moderator wants to move it, I would not mind.

Comment: @larsks I tried to illustrate it with an example, but by `mv foo.jpg ~/bar.jpg` **foo.jpg** will no longer exist. It will be renamed **bar.jpg**. I would like a symbolic link with the old name and structure **foo/foo.jpg** to point toward the newly named file.

Comment: @gpops you'd probably get more answers that way.  By the way, I was the upvote, not the downvote.

Comment: @Cody: I do think it's off topic here.  Linux and coreutils are "general-purpose computing software".

Comment: @BenVoigt It's close.   could go either way.  It also falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers", which [is considered on-topic.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Cody: You have to read that as "software tools commonly used *exclusively* by programmers" (and other software development roles, including testers).  Software that are rarely used by non-programmers are ok (example: version control).  But software for which programmers are a trivial fraction of users are not.  Otherwise all major OSes would be covered.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think it's arguably on-topic here (which also means arguably off-topic), but _definitely_ on-topic at the unix site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be pointed at unix.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** After clarification, your question might be reworded as: *"Can a symlink name (or any Unix/Linux filename) contain a forward slash `/`?"*

The answer is: No. The forward slash `/` is [hard-wired at the file system level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename) as a path separator, separating directories and their content.

**But maybe this can help you:**

In some cases, symlinks to directories are useful. The following existing path

```
/a/b/c/d
```

could be symlinked into `/somewhere`

```
$ ln -s /a /somewhere
```

so that `/somewhere/a/b/c/d` becomes a valid filesystem path:

```
$ ls /somewhere/
a
$ ls /somewhere/a/
b
# ... etc
```

I think that's as close as you can get.

Comment: I explained what I'm looking for further in a comment under Cody's post. So, ideally, I don't want the directory **foo** to exist at all.  I'd like the name of the link to be **foo/foo.jpg** to trick software into thinking the directory **foo** still exists and **foo.jpg** is still inside it. I don't think this is possible, but that's why I asked on here :)

Comment: @gpops - I see, post revised. `/` in unix filenames are impossible, but maybe directory symlinks can help you.

Answer (score 1):

My Unix skills are shaky, but from my understanding of symbolic links, **it is impossible to make a symbolic link follow a renamed file**.  This is because a symbolic link basically just points to the name of a file, and doesn't know anything about it; when the file it points is moved/deleted, it just points to the name of a file that doesn't exist anymore.

As you mentioned, you can solve your problem by creating a hardlink.

Reference: http://www.nixtutor.com/freebsd/understanding-symbolic-links/

Comment: There's a decent chance I misunderstood the question; if so, just ask me to clarify and/or downvote gratuitously.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond, but yes, I should clarify my question further: I am talking about a torrent client. The client is looking on my computer for a specific file nested in a specific directory (ie. **~/foo/foo.jpg**). Problem is, I moved the file to another directory and renamed it (ie. **bar.jpg**). I want to create a symbolic link with the name **foo/foo.jpg** pointing toward **bar.jpg** so that my torrent client recognizes it and my directory/filename organization remains the same. I note in the OP that this may not be possible, but I'm not a seasoned Linux user so I asked.