# ftp_mkdir(): Can't create directory: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ftp

I am having trouble making remote directory using ftp.

I am getting error as `Warning: ftp_mkdir(): Can't create directory: No such file or directory`

I am trying this way.

```
$connection = ftp_connect($hostname) or die('Couldn\'t connect to ftp server'); 
$login = ftp_login($connection, $username, $password) or die('Couldn\'t log_in to ftp server');
ftp_pasv($connection, true);
if ($login){echo 'Connected Successfully.';}else{echo 'Cannot connect.';}

$dir = '2014/04/09';



if(!@ftp_chdir($connection, '/public_html/images/'.$dir)){
    $ftp_mkdir = ftp_mkdir($connection, '/public_html/images/'.$dir);
    if($ftp_mkdir){
        echo 'Remote directory created successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Error creating remote directory';
    }
}
else{
        echo 'Remote directory exist';
}
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what OS you are using but on Windows you can't have files with a "/" character in the name.

Comment: @Scott I am on windows7 and using linux hosting.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you are allowed that character in your file name. try changing `$dir = '2014/04/09';` to `$dir = '2014-04-09';`

Comment: @Scott that worked I get directory as images/2014-04-09, But the thing is that I want to make directory like images/2014/04/09/image.png, How can I do that.

Comment: Just for reference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows `* . " / \ [ ] : ; | = ,` are reserved characters and are **not** allowed to be used in your file names.

For Linux I think it's just `/` and `\0`

The `/` character is used to traverse file directories in Linux hence why it is forbidden to use as a file name.

For more info on illegal file names: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved%5Fcharacters%5Fand%5Fwords

You will have to substitute your `/` symbol with something else such as `-`

In replay to your comment: 
To make a directory like `images/2014/04/09/image.png`

You just need to create your folders on your server. So `images/2014/04/09/image.png` is a file called `image.png` which is inside the folder `09` which is inside the folder `04` which is inside the folder `2014` which is inside the folder `images`

Hope that makes scene?

Comment: You said You just need to create your folders on your server? do i have to manually create the folders or can i create it using ftp.

Comment: You can do either... But by the looks of things you are following some naming convention with dates so you might want to write yourself a PHP script to handle this. So the script would get todays date, then check to see if there is already a file for this year, then month, then day, if no file found on these create a file.

Comment: You mean to say I have to create one after another these directories. Like create year directory first then month directory then date directory then put file.

Comment: Yes, to get a directory like this `images/2014/04/09/image.png` as you can't use the `/` character for file names.

Comment: Ok I think I have to make these directories like one after another as there is naming restriction. Thanks for taking time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and fixed by creating one folder at a time. I was not able to make ftp_chdir create the entire path on a single command.

So to create this:

```
$dir = '2014/04/09';
```

I had to create first:

```
$dir = '/2014/';
```

Then:

```
$dir = '/2014/04/';
```

At last:

```
$dir = '/2014/04/09/';
```

And then submit your file '/2014/04/09/image.jpg'.

Worked like a charm.