# Shell script print the path of all sub directory

Tags: shell

**My Script:**

```
 cd /var/www/try/
 sort -u
 files="$(find -L "/var/www/try/" -type d)"
 echo "Count: $(echo -n "$files" | wc -l)"
 echo "$files" | while read file; do
 echo $file >> filename.csv
 done
```

**Output :**

```
/var/www/try
/var/www/try/cat
```

**Output Should be :**

```
var-www-try
var-www-try-cat
```

**Second Case :**
 any character except / as some fo my folder name contain / like for e.g.

```
"tv/dvd"
```

**Output genrated :**

```
 /var/www/try/cat/tv/dvd
```

**Output Should be :**

```
 var-www-try-cat-tv/dvd-
```

Comment: Is the dash after dvd a typo?  var-www-try-cat-tv/dvd-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `sed`, which is a popular tool for string replacing tasks.

```
>> x=$(echo '/var/www/try/cat/tv/' | sed 's/\//-/g')
>> echo $x
-var-www-try-cat-tv-
>> x=${x:1}
>> echo $x
var-www-try-cat-tv-
```

edit:
In response to your second case:

> as some fo my folder name contain /

Maybe there's a misunderstanding here but you should not have a / in a filename. See [Is it possible to use "/" in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename)

Comment: can u please help me with how can i replace every first slash of the line with something else using sed command

Comment: sure, here's an example: echo '/this/starts/with/a/slash/' | sed 's/^\//somethingelse/' will yield somethingelsethis/starts/with/a/slash/