# Issue saving a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I am trying to save a figure. Something quite simple.

The program that makes the plots receives a list called "data"

```
data['Reading [V/dec]','OK values', 'Defects', 'Valids', 'Non valids']

fig.savefig(data[0]+'.png')
```

If I use the code above, the figure is just not saved.

If I do like this:

```
data['Reading [V per dec]','OK values', 'Defects', 'Valids', 'Non valids']

fig.savefig(data[0]+'.png')
```

The figure is saved.

So I am wondering why I cannot use **'Reading [V/dec]'** as a name for my .png file. And how to make it take the name as it is 'Reading [V/dec]'.

Just one more comment, according to an aswer I got, I have to say that I am using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with matplotlib really, and is instead because of how operating systems handle directories. `/` is often used for separating directories, i.e. my file is stored here `/path/to/my/file.py`. As such, it is unlikely that you're allowed to use the symbol `/` in a filename as it would confuse matters far too much.

This is definitely not allowed in Windows and Ubuntu, not sure about OS X or other Linux distros but I suspect it is not allowed for all.

Comment: No. Go and try to create a text file called `my/text/file.txt`. It will fail.

Comment: On Windows the filename cannot have any of the following symbols `\/:*?"<>|`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Comment: IIRC forward slashes are valid for filenames (on both *nix and M$), they will be interpreted as path separators though. And in most situation the directory path would have to exist in the first place to not raise an IOError.

Comment: When I tried to make a file using `vi` it told me that the directory did not exist, which suggests you are correct.