# Ruby unexpected keyword end

Tags: ruby

I have code:

```
results = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com.uk"]

results.each do |results| 
  File.open("#{results}.html", "w") do |file|
    file.write(RestClient.get(#{result}))
  end
end
```

When I run the program, it gives me an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

I have two `do`-s and two `end`-s. Please help.

Comment: what if you put it in one line:   `File.open("#{results}.html", "w") { |file|
    file.write(RestClient.get(#{result})) }` ? will it still throw an error?

Comment: Please post the full error message and the according line numbers. Furthermore it seems like you should check when to use `results` and when `result`.

Comment: Yes! Besides, I have another "do". Tried using {} for both, still an error.

Comment: What about results/result?
Full error message for code posted:

Comment: 6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Answer (score 6):

`#` is used for string interpolation, but only within an appropriate [string literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings):

```
File.open("#{results}.html", "w")
#          ^^^^^^^^^^
#          string interpolation
```

Outside of strings, `#` starts a [comment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/_lib/racc/rdoc/grammar_en_rdoc.html#label-Comments):

```
file.write(RestClient.get(#{result}))
#                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
#                         comment
```

Your editor should be able to highlight it accordingly:

[image: vim screenshot]

To "fix" it, use:

```
file.write(RestClient.get(result))
```

BTW, there's also another typo in your code:

```
results.each do |results|
```

Should be:

```
results.each do |result|
```

`result` then refers to a single element within your `results` array (double check your code for `result` vs. `results`).

Comment: thanks! but using your 'fix' gives:
4:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://www.google.com.html (Errno::ENOENT)
 from trytrytry.rb:4:in `new'
 from trytrytry.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
 from trytrytry.rb:3:in `each'
 from trytrytry.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: Have also corrected "results" and 'result'. Thanks!

Comment: new code:

results = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com.uk"]

results.each do |result| 
  file = File.new("#{result}.html", "w") do |file| 
    file.write(RestClient.get(result))
    file.close
  end
end

Still doesnt work

Comment: You were correct the first time using `File#open` instead of `File#new`. Having`/` characters is causing problems I imagine, as in your original post.

Comment: @HenryChan you get a *"No such file or directory"* error, because `/` indicates a directory separator. `index.html` is a valid filename whereas `http://google.com` is not.

Comment: thanks James. How do I correct / problem?  I have actually tried replacing the URLs with "a", "b" and the code works. However, I want to save the file as its URL name, and it gives me error.

Comment: @HenryChan If your question about 'unexpected keyword end' has been answered, but you need further help for _other_, unrelated problems in your code, please post new, specific questions via 'Ask Question' instead of here in the comments. If appropriate, link from one question to the other, or even both ways.

Comment: @Stefan I see! but all my URLs contain / . Do I just use escape character to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I would omit `http://` altogether and add it back in later if you need it, but yes you could replace the `/` with some encoded representation. This answer may be of use (not Ruby related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288