# Create directories with '/' in the name

Tags: java, linux

I am working on a script to create sub-directories with names, that are fetched from a database.
I am passing 2 parameters, for creating 2 directories, one inside the other. Code snippet is below.

```
File files = new File(name1+"\"+name2);
if (!files.exists()) {
    if (files.mkdirs()) {
        System.out.println("sub directories created successfully");
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed to create sub directories");
    }
}
```

The "name2" parameter is of the format "abc/d/e" and this has to be the name of the directory.
Using the above code, it create individual folders as abc,d,e.
I am working on java & linux platform

Any solution for this.

Comment: \ is for special characters. You must use "\\" to close the String correctly.

Comment: Filenames cannot contain forward slashes. Forward slash is the path separator in Linux.

Comment: @Arnab Backslash or forward-? Title says one thing and code an other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use "/" in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename)

Comment: @Biffen The mention of `abc/d/e` and the resulting treatment suggests the backslash is a typo.

Comment: @chepner Sure does, but a clarification would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux file system entries (file names, directory names, socket names, etc) cannot contain `/`. This character is reserved as the path separator. What you want to do is not possible.

Comment: actually you can with `mkdir -p foo/bar`. Not quite sure how that maps to the Java file objects.

Comment: That creates a directory `foo` if it does not exist, with a directory `bar` inside it. It does not create a single directory named `foo/bar`.

Comment: true, but from his code it looks like he actually wants to create subdirectories.

Comment: "The "name2" parameter is of the format "abc/d/e" and this has to be the name of the directory. Using the above code, it create individual folders as abc,d,e." He *wants* a single directory, but he's getting three directories.