# Maven Assembly create outputDirectory

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Not sure what is going on.  Given this assembly description, I expect maven-assembly-plugin to include a war file under the outputDirectory within the tar.  However it is instead using the directory name as part of the file name.

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
       <outputDirectory>modules/rxspend-app/files</outputDirectory>
       <includes>
           <include>${project.groupId}:rxspend-web:war</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

when I expand the tar:

```
-rw-rw-r-- vagrant/vagrant 22919347 2015-10-09 14:13 modules/rxspend-app/files/rxspend-web-3.0.7-20151009.140153-788.war
drwxr-xr-x 0/0                    0 2015-10-09 14:29 modules/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0                    0 2015-10-09 14:29 modules/jboss/
```

I don't know if the outputDirectory needs to pre-exist or not, or how to get it created.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The tar has the correct war (`rxspend-web-3.0.7-20151009.140153-788.war`) in the directory you specified (`modules/rxspend-app/files`).

Comment: no it has the war with the name "modules/rxspend-app/files/rxspend-web-3.0.7-20151009.140153-788.war"   it should have the war with the name rxspend-web-3.0.7-20151009.140153-788.war in the directory modules/rxspend-app/files (note that the first entry is NOT a directory, the filenamejust makes it look like one)

Comment: I'm confused, how can there be a `/` [inside a filename](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9847288/1743880)?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that it is a tar directory issue?  When I unpack the structure is as expected