# Node/Express res.download(path, filename) doesn't support strings with slashes in the filename?

Tags: node.js, express, download

If I write:

```
res.status(200).download(p, 'he/lo/ldkaf/fd.mp3');
```

the download will show up as:

```
fd.mp3
```

currently the only workaround is turning all the slashes into spaces:

```
res.status(200).download(p, 'he/lo/ldkaf/fd.mp3'.split('/').join(' '));
```

But I'd like to keep the slashes. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to `.download()` is a filename only (no path) that should be offered as the default filename in the browser if/when the browser saves the file.  Slashes are not allowed because they are not a legal character in a filename (since they are typically path separators) and any path suggested by a server would be ignored by a browser (as a security issue).

Comment: I considered this, but (at least on *nix) slashes are supported in filenames. I suppose this is correct and I'll just have to swap them for another character. Thanks.

Comment: @underscore - Not sure how you think *nix can have a forward slash in a filename: [Is it possible to use “/” in a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename)

Comment: Then just OS X*

My bad.