# Rename files with a forward slash in the filename (python)

Tags: python, filenames, os.walk, os.path, invalid-characters

We have a bunch of old files (1990s) that we're preparing to import into a new system. Some of these files have a forward slash / in their filename and we need to rename these before importing (they're going to end up in Azure).

We've got some python code that walks the directory:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
  for filename in files:
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

And then attempts to rename any files it doesn't like the look of using `os.rename`. This works fine except on files with a forward slash in the filename - even `os.path.exists` fails on these files using the `path` calculated above.

In `os.path.exists` we've tried replacing:

- the colon with a forward slash
- the colon with an escaped forward slash /
- the colon with an escaped colon :

And we always get a `False` back. And a "No such file or directory" error when attempting an `os.path.rename`. The filename has a forward slash in it but it's treated by the OS as a colon : - at least that's what `os.walk` reports the filename as.

We also get an `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when doing

```
fileobj = open(path)
```

We can't rename the files manually in the Finder. You'll notice the Finder displays the filename with the forward slash (sorry no rep so links to images):
[finder rename error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXcBp.png)

Or from the command line - the filename is displayed here with the colon:
[terminal - no such file or directory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYIPT.png)

Windows won't list the files in File Explorer or Powershell.

So I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to how to go about renaming these files or somehow getting rid of the forward slashes please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: Thanks @JonatasCD - the problem we have isn't with the file paths and we aren't doing this processing in Windows. The problem is to do with filenames that contain a forward slash.

Comment: But I understood that the referred question could provide a similar solution for you. Maybe I was wrong. Did you check it, @ben-wood?

Comment: Is the processing done on Linux? If so, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Comment: Yeah thanks @JonatasCD - we're using os.path.join to create our file paths but reading that question more closely (thanks for the nudge) perhaps we need to try prefixing the filename with the raw string r prefix. I'll try it...

Comment: Thanks @dm295 I read that one too - it made me think there is perhaps no way to rename these files except on a different OS

Answer (score -1):

I used one of the solutions proposed in ["Is it possible to use “/” in a filename?" thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename). Here my version of it in python:

```
filename.replace('/', '\N{FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS}')
```

That works only if your target filesystem supports unicode in file names.

Comment: Is there a full example.  Trying to do that but is that filename under os.walk?

Comment: Add one more line into the original code of the question :
    filename = filename.replace('/', '\N{FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS}')