# python automatically string to directory when create a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want create a file.My file name like this ->"blabla/blabla" this is not path ,this is a string

and should be "blabla/blabla.txt"

```
with open(fullnameofjob+".txt", "w+") as f:
                f.write("somethink")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'blabla/blabla'
```

How can I fix that?
[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8iqq.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do this, you could build the name with the unicode value for a division slash and save the file with that:

```
fullnameofjob = 'blabla' + u'\u2215' + 'blabla'
with open(fullnameofjob+".txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("somethink")
```

Although this just looks like a slash, it's not actually a slash as such included in file paths and is probably going to cause you problems later down the line. Unfortunately you cannot have `/` in the file basename on unix or windows.

Comment: ok . I will  try "/" replace to specific something and after string.replace("<specific something>","/") . Thanks for your help

Comment: thats a great idea .Thanks

Comment: @oguzzeyveli No, this is a really bad idea. Don't use weird unicode characters in file names. It's just going to cause trouble.

Comment: even though the solution works, it's a terrible idea to use `\ or /` characters in file names. I would suggest you to have a different structure. You can also check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Comment: Yes it is not a good idea, as indicated by myself and the previous comment. +1 for the link to extra info though.