# Rename fails but does work with -n (no action) option

Tags: linux, filesystems, rename

Im trying to rename some files with the format `Week_XX_2018-XX-XX_-_2018-XX-XX.md` to `Week_XX_2018-XX-XX/2018-XX-XX.md`. So changing `_-_` to `/`.

I tried to use `rename` and first tested it with the `-n` option. This works fine and shows something like this for all the files:

```
$ rename -n 's/_-_/\//g' *
rename(Week_01_2018-12-03_-_2018-12-09.md, Week_01_2018-12-03/2018-12-09.md)
...
```

However, when executed without the `-n`option the command fails. It says

```
Can't rename Week_01_2018-12-03_-_2018-12-19.md Week_01_2018-12-03/2018-12-09: No such file or directory
```

Why does this happen? How can the test of the command work but not the actual command?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash`; `rename` is an external program (and there are at least two different versions of it, each taking different arguments).

Comment: @JohnKugelman I don't edit tags to criticize OP; tags are used as a tool to draw in people who can best answer a question. I feel the tags related to the core issue better serve this purpose. P.s.: Sorry I accidentially reverted your revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character '/' is special as it is used as path delimiter. See [Is it possible to use "/" in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename) for a more detailed answer on why your rename fails.