# Jszip- create files with a literal `/` in the name?

Tags: javascript, jszip

[image]I want to create an image file named:

`jszip.file('a/b.png', image) jszip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) { saveAs(content, image + '.zip'); })`

The results are equivalent:
`zip.folder('a').file('b.png', 'image')` // equivalent

Is there a way to create an image with such a name, rather than splitting it into a directory??

Comment: I don't know jszip, but, try: `jszip.file("a\/b.png", image)` - escaping the forward-slash.

Comment: @iAmOren It is still separated into your directory

Comment: Ok, then: No...  See @DynasticSponge's answer below.  In the reference someone suggested using character that looks like "/" but isn't "/".  How about using something else to separate - like "."?

Comment: @iAmOren I don't understand that, can you help me for example?

Comment: `jszip.file('a.b.png', image)`

Comment: It just doesn't create a folder, but it still doesn't change. ' to '/' in the file name

Comment: Right - I was giving an example of using SOMETHING ELSE ("." instead of "/"), because, it seems, "/" CANNOT be part of a file name.  
Have you seen it anywhere?  Why do you want it?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a limitation of code.. its limitation of filesystem...  reference this StackOverflow question

[Is it possible to use "/" in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and on my MacOS machine I observed that it is possible to use slashes in filenames. I named a file with a slash and dragged and dropped it to the terminal and I saw that MacOS replaced the slash with a colon.

Since it appears you are using a MacOS machine, to get your desired output simply replace occurrences of the slash character with a colon.

```
jszip.file(filename.replace('/', ':'), image)
```