# Bash: how to rename a file to a string containing forward slashes?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file that I want to rename to a date like "20/02/21", but if I do `mv file.txt 20/02/21` it interprets the forward slashes as referencing sub-folders. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: [Is it possible to use "/" in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename) Short answer - you can't do that.

Comment: @gkeenley : See [here](https://www.lemoda.net/unix/filename-chars/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do it. On Unix forward slash `/` is used to
separate directories and cannot be used in the filename. You have to
use another delimiter - `20\02\21`, `20-02-21`, `20.02.21` etc.